# SQL Server Handle No Data in Some Cases

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my sql code below:

```
SELECT 'Template Name: ' + (SELECT Template.TemplateName FROM Stationery INNER JOIN Template ON
            Template.Template_Id=Stationery.FrontTemplate_Id INNER JOIN [Order] ON
            [Order].Stationery_Id=Stationery.Stationery_Id
            WHERE [Order].Order_Id in (9513)) + 
    ' | Back Template: ' + (SELECT ISNULL(Template.TemplateName, '') FROM Stationery INNER JOIN Template ON
                    Template.Template_Id=Stationery.BackTemplate_Id INNER JOIN [Order] ON
                    [Order].Stationery_Id=Stationery.Stationery_Id
                    WHERE [Order].Order_Id in (9513)) +
    ' Other Information : ' + (SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), OtherInformation) 
                    FROM Template INNER JOIN [Order] 
                    ON Template.TemplateName=[Order].ProductName 
                    WHERE [Order].Order_Id in (9513)) +
    ' User Comments: ' + (SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), [Order].IndividualComments),'')
                    FROM [Order] WHERE [Order].Order_Id in (9513))
FROM [Order] WHERE [Order].Order_Id in (9513)
```

The problem comes from the following section of the code, which sometimes fails because of non existing data:

```
SELECT ISNULL(Template.TemplateName, '') FROM Stationery INNER JOIN Template ON
Template.Template_Id=Stationery.BackTemplate_Id INNER JOIN [Order] ON
[Order].Stationery_Id=Stationery.Stationery_Id
WHERE [Order].Order_Id in (9513)
```

In the code above `FrontTemplate_Id` is always populated, but `BackTemplate_Id` is sometimes `NULL`, which means there's no data in the other tables. Not NULL, but just plain NOTHING. If this happens, the whole code block returns a `NULL`, instead of just leaving a blank and continuing. Which is what I tried with the `ISNULL` part I added

Long story short: I need to handle if no data exists for my `Stationery` and `[Order]` tables,  and avoid the whole thing returning a `NULL`.

Comment: Use `CONCAT` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use ISNULL on the sub-query not only on selected column -

```
 SELECT 'Template Name: ' + ISNULL( (SELECT Template.TemplateName FROM 
 Stationery INNER JOIN Template ON
        Template.Template_Id=Stationery.FrontTemplate_Id INNER JOIN [Order] ON
        [Order].Stationery_Id=Stationery.Stationery_Id
        WHERE [Order].Order_Id in (9513))  ,'') +
```

Comment: Wasn't aware I could do that. Perfect!